# Need help to find bug in factoring code

Tags: java, debugging, biginteger, factorization

I am coding a program to factor a number into is prime factors. The program works as follows:

1) Input a number that you wish to factor (I will refer to is as "inputNumber")

2) Test to see if you can divide inputNumber by 2,3,5 and 7 (first 4 prime numbers). if you can divide by any of these, then do so as many times as you can (i.e. 12 can be divided by 2 twice, after this, there is a remainder of 3)
*note* every time I divide by a number, I store that number in an array list and I keep the remainder for further testing

3) Starting with i=11 (the next prime number) in a while loop, I do the following:

```
while (i < remainder+1) { 
divides by i? yes: store i, 
repeat until you cant divide by i. i=i+2, 
divides by i? yes: store i, repeat until you can't divide by i.
 i=i+4, same as before... i=i+2... 
and finally stop the loop at i=i+2 
}
```

this way, every successful iteration of the while loop will divide the remainder by numbers finishing by 1,3,7,9. We do not need to test even numbers since we divided by 2 already, nor do we need to test the ones ending by 5 since we already divided by 5. In the end, we

This is a very neat algorithm since it its much much faster than factoring a number by testing one number after the other, in fact, you only need to test 40% of all numbers.

My question is: When I tried factoring 84738329279, a number picked randomly, it omits to put the last prime factor in the list, I can't quite figure this out. the only factors that show up are 41, 61 and 61. Can someone help me find what I'm doing wrong? here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
                    // create a scanner object for inputs
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            // prompt user for number to factor
            System.out.print("enter a number to factor: ");
            String digits = in.next();
            BigInteger BigDigits = new BigInteger(digits);

            BigInteger[] results = factor.factorThis(BigDigits);


            System.out.print("Factors are ");
            for (int i=0; i<results.length;i++){
            System.out.print(results[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.math.BigInteger;


public class factor {

// Returns the prime factors of the BigInteger number
public static BigInteger[] factorThis(BigInteger number) {

    BigInteger i = new BigInteger("11");
    ArrayList<BigInteger> divisors = new ArrayList<BigInteger>(0);

    BigInteger[] firstPrimes = new BigInteger[4];
    firstPrimes[0] = new BigInteger("2");
    firstPrimes[1] = new BigInteger("3");
    firstPrimes[2] = new BigInteger("5");
    firstPrimes[3] = new BigInteger("7");

    // loop that test for first 4 prime numbers
    for (int l=0;l<4;l++){
        while ((number.mod(firstPrimes[l])).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {
            number = number.divide(firstPrimes[l]);
            divisors.add(firstPrimes[l]);
        }
    }


    // loop that factors only numbers finishing by 1,3,7,9
    while (i.compareTo(number) == -1){

        // check for ending by 1
        if ((number.mod(i)).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {
            while (number.mod(i).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0){
                number = number.divide(i);
                divisors.add(i);
            }
        }
        else if ((number.mod(i)).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) != 0){
            i=i.add(firstPrimes[0]);
        }

        // check for ending by 3
        if ((number.mod(i)).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {
            while (number.mod(i).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0){
                number = number.divide(i);
                divisors.add(i);
            }
        }
        else if ((number.mod(i)).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) != 0){
            i=i.add(firstPrimes[0].multiply(firstPrimes[0]));
        }

        //check for ending by 7
        if ((number.mod(i)).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {
            while (number.mod(i).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0){
                number = number.divide(i);
                divisors.add(i);
            }
        }
        else if ((number.mod(i)).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) != 0){
            i=i.add(firstPrimes[0]);
        }

        // check for ending by 9
        if ((number.mod(i)).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {
            while (number.mod(i).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0){
                number = number.divide(i);
                divisors.add(i);
            }
        }
        else if ((number.mod(i)).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) != 0){
            i=i.add(firstPrimes[0]);
        }
    }

    // store prime factors into a BigInt array
    String[] strArrayDivisors = divisors.toString().replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","").replaceAll("\\s","").split(",");

    BigInteger[] BigIntDivisors = new BigInteger[strArrayDivisors.length];

    for(int j=0;j<strArrayDivisors.length;j++){
        BigIntDivisors[j] = new BigInteger(strArrayDivisors[j]);
    }

    // returns all factors of "number"
    return BigIntDivisors;

}   
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `84738329279 = 41 * 61 * 61 * 555439`.  Your 41, 61, and 61 are correct.

But when your algorithm terminates, you are left with the last prime number still in `number`.  You'll need to add code that tests `number` at the end: if it's `1`, then you're already finished, else it needs to add it to `divisors` so it gets printed later.

Comment: The problem line is this one: `while (i.compareTo(number) == -1)`.  When i == number == 555439, this test will prevent you from going into your tests.  No special test for `1` is needed, you just need to execute your code for i == number and you'll have it.

Comment: Also, your code would be far clearer if instead of `i=i.add(firstPrimes[0].multiply(firstPrimes[0]));` you defined a BigInteger called `two` and then did `i=i.add(two.multiply(two))`.  Code readability matters; look for ways to make it easier to read via refactoring, clear variable names, etc.

Comment: And variable names should start with a lowercase letter while type names start with a capital; `BigInteger[] BigIntDivisors` isn't good practice.

Comment: thanks so much! it seems so obvious now that you stated the problem! and thanks for the tips! I will definitely keep them in mind!